# Nested collections in CSV Helper mapping

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, csvhelper

I have a collection Car including fields for date of production, car name, production place - this is a new model named ProductionPlace including City, Address and Id, and there is another collection in Cars which is Creator - including name, surname and country.

So this basically looks like this

```
Cars
{
ProductionDate,
Name,
ProductionPlace
  {
    Id,
    City,
    Address
  },
Creator
  {
   Name,
   Surname,
   Country
  }
```

How can I map those using CSV Helper?
I'm getting "there is no field named Creator" for example. I can simply map fields but not collection nested in my main collection

Edit

```
My code as far looks like that 

public void MapCar()
{
Map(mapping => mapping.Car).ConvertUsing(
row => { List<Car> car = new List<Car>
{
ProductionDate = row.GetField("ProductionDate"),
Name = row.GetField("Name"),
ProductionPlace = new ProductionPlace
{
Id = row.GetField("Id"),
City = row.GetField("City"),
Address = row.GetField("Address")
},
Creator = new Creator
{
Name = row.GetField("Name"),
Surname = row.GetField("Surname"),
Country = row.GetFiele("Country")
}
};)}
```

Both Creator and ProductionPlace are separate models. And Car is a model using those two as it's fields.

Comment: Can you please show your code so we can further help you?

Comment: When you say "map those", what exactly do you mean? What output are you expecting?

Comment: As an output I'm expecting a collection of type Car.

Comment: @San show your attempt please. In the above, what does that data represent, a class, text etc.? The data above isn't valid for anything I know of.

Comment: @zaggler I've updated my question

Comment: Can you give example CSV data? The header row and a couple data rows.

Comment: @Josh Close the point is I'm trying to map those fields into CSV file :) so for now I don't have one. I would like to know if it's even possible to map them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Really the only issue you have right now is that both `Car` and `Creator` have the same name for the property `Name`. If you use the CsvHelper name attribute, you can give them different names in your CsvHeader and the rest will map without you having to do anything else.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var input = new StringBuilder();
    input.AppendLine("ProductionDate,CarName,Id,City,Address,CreatorName,Surname,Country");
    input.AppendLine("2021-06-03,Tesla,1,MyCity,MyAddress,Bob,Jones,MyCountry");
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader(input.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Car>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
    [Name("CarName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProductionPlace ProductionPlace { get; set; }
    public Creator Creator { get; set; }
}

public class ProductionPlace 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Creator
{
    [Name("CreatorName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```